# 2d matrix allocation function segfault (matrix returned by param)

Tags: c, arrays, 2d, malloc, exc-bad-access

i'm having a problem when trying to write the second row of the matrix (segfault `exc_bad_access` and `kern_invalid_address`) allocated with the following function:

Here is my alloc function:

```
int amatrix(char*** m, const int i, const int j) 
{

    int k;

    (*m) = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*) * i);
    if ((*m) == NULL) {
        return ERROR;
    }

    for (k = 0; k < i; k++) {
        (*m)[k] = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * j);
        if ((*m)[k] == NULL) {
            return ERROR;
        }
    }

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

I call it by using:

```
char** matrix;
if (amatrix(&matrix, i, j)) { ...
```

**Edit:**
As requested:

```
#define ERROR 00
#define SUCCESS 01
```

The access where the trouble is:

```
int gmatrix(char*** m, const int i, const int j)
{
int k, l;

for (k = 0; k < i; k++) {
    for (l = 0; l < j; l++) {
        printf("Matrix[%d][%d] = ", k, l);
        scanf(" %c", m[k][l]);
    }
}

return SUCCESS;
}
```

Thank you for the quick replies!

Comment: Could you share a complete example (including `ERROR`and `SUCCESS` values, the code trying to write to the allocated matrix, …)?

Comment: Can we see your access? Everything seems fine here.

Comment: I'd declare a 2d character array as `char c2d[42][43]`. Or allocate it `char * pc2d = calloc(42*43, 1)`

Comment: Do not cast `malloc()` in C: http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/694576

Comment: The post is updated, hope you guys can figure it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `gmatrix` function should take `m` as a `char**` parameter, not `char***`, because it does not need to change its value like `amatrix` does (only what it points to).

Then you should change the scanf call to:

```
scanf(" %c", &m[k][l]);
```

Your current code (with `char*** m`) doesn't work because `m[k]` will give undefined behavior when `k!=0`, because `m` points only to a single `char**`.

If `m` is a `char***`, the scanf call would need to look like:

```
scanf(" %c", &(*m)[k][l]);
```

Comment: tyvm, it worked!
I wasn't aware of the undefined behavior, could you explain more? Why it's undefined when k != 0?

Comment: @bellati: Suppose you have `int a; int *p = &a`. Then `p[0]` is OK but `p[1]` is undefined because `p` only points to one `int`. The same is true here, except you have `char**` instead of `int`.

Comment: Nice, now I understand. How about a freematrix function? Does free needs to modify the address or only what the matrix points to? Also is there any way to test if something has been freed? Tyvm in advance!

Comment: @bellati: For `free` you don't need to modify the address. And there is no way to test if a pointer has been freed.